# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILe: loading data form text file auto incerment syntax

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load data from a .txt file into mysql.  The table looks like this:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_name   | varchar(10)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| listings    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| connections | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| flags       | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| days        | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| email       | varchar(30)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| suspend     | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

when I load the data using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` how do I handle the `user_id` column?  All the other items have data already.  I'd like the database to assign the user_id's.  Is that possible?

What should column under `user_id` look like in the text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following:

```
name   \N    2    4    2    100    emal@mail.com    o
```

Each entry was automatically given the correct id in place of the \N.

If there's a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

*"You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column"* read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Example:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE tablename (user_name, @skip, listings, connections, flags, days, email, suspend);
```